# Converting a simple app to have a tab bar

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I have a question that is similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398161/converting-an-utility-application-2-view-controllers-to-a-tab-bar-application), but slightly different (or my skills don't allow me to follow the directions with confidence).  I have an existing game app that has one view controller and one nib and works fine.  I want to convert it to have a tab bar controller.  I want the original, existing view controller to be on the first tab, and I wrote a new view controller and a new nib for the second tab, which will be dedicated to game settings.  At this stage, the app builds and runs fine with the new nib and view controllers in the project (but with no further edits -- no attempt to add the tab bar controller etc).  The modified app should simply have two views each accessible from one of the two tabs.

Sorry for the long bkgnd.  I'm following the accepted answer to the above-referenced question.  The first 4 steps I have done or can do.  The 5th step is to `Delete the old version of your Main View Controller from the NIB file and also remove the IBOutlet property from the Application Delegate`.  I don't think I have such an `IBOutlet` in my app (which is different from the OP's app).  Should I delete the object view controller shown in this list?  Or am I on the wrong track here?

[image]

**Additional Info**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Set up view controller & load a clean view

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.viewController = [[P3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"P3ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

    NSLog(@"P3ViewController now active");

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: how is your current view controller and nib loaded? can you show your `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method?

Comment: @Rog I edited the question to provide the method.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you in the right direction...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    YourNewViewController *ynvc = [[YourNewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNewViewController" bundle:nil];
    YourCurrentViewController *ycvc = [[YourCurrentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourCurrentViewController" bundle:nil];
    [tbc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:ynvc, ycvc, nil]];
    self.window.rootViewController = tbc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: OK, thank you, great, I understand this and have put it in place with appropriate modifications to the names. I must have to make some other changes.  Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: What else do you want to know? This will basically create a tab bar controller with your 2 view controllers assigned to it, then make it the root view controller of your application window.

Comment: Well, going back to the original answer I was following, I am wondering about whether I need to delete the view controller and re-wire the nib?

Comment: You don't need to make any changes to your existing nib (apart from resizing your views) so they can fit within the space available now that you have a tab bar at the bottom.

Comment: Right you are!  I'm so glad I asked, as the answer I was following was apparently too specific to the OP's app.  Thank you so much.

Comment: OK, so the application runs, loads up the tab bar controller and puts the first nib into the first tab.  I can click on either tab with no problem. First nib works fine.  But the second tab nib does not load (and it's loadView method is never called).  So I'm missing some connection in IB, right?  I can see that the connections between the two view controllers are different: for the working VC, the file's owner has a connection to a view (under 'searchDisplayController') but the non-working VC file owner does not have such an option.  What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you have a loadView method if you are loading a nib? That is only if you are creating your entire view programmatically in which case you don't need a nib. Your nibs file owner should be your view controller subclass and you can then connect your main view to the view outlet in the controller.

Comment: Thanks.  The real answer is I have a loadView because I have cobbled this thing together from various templates and I've been learning as I go (so it's pretty dirty I guess).  For my first VC the loadView sets up some singletons: buttons and configures the game; maybe this belongs elsewhere.  You were correct: my nibs file owner class was not set and now that is correct, but the view doesn't load (but loadView on the 2nd VC is active).  This makes me wonder why my first view loads at all, I'll hunt that down and that'll probably give me the answer as to why the 2nd VC doesn't load.

Comment: If you need to setup stuff like that use the `initWithCoder:` method of your view controller. I'd also advise you to have a look at Apple's view controller programming guide as you are likely get lost again very quickly.

Comment: But in a nutshell, if you implement `loadView` in your view controller the NIB view will be ignored as load view is expected to setup the main view of your view controller (`self.view`). If you are loading a nib via interface builder the init method called will be `initWithCoder:` (this is valid for ANY interface builder objects). If you are instantiating a view controller programatically you want to use `initWithNibName:bundle:`.

Comment: Thank you Rog.  I've read that doc but it's time to read again as I've learned a lot since the first read. Thanks for the multiple suggestions.

Comment: [returning to project after delay due to life] I've looked around a bit at `initWithCoder` docs and I'm wondering why I would have to do this at all.  It worked when there was only a single view.  `initWithCoder` sounds like I'm doing the work of the compiler.  Can you give me a quick comment on why that approach is necessary?  Thank you!